# x2go: Connection failed, cannot create remote file

Tags: 18.04, x2goclient

When I try to server with x2goclient, I get this error:

[image]

how can I fix it?

**UPDATE**: Both computers are on same local network with no firewalls, ssh connection between them works perfectly. Both computers are running Ubuntu 18.04, software versions: **x2goserver 4.1.0.0-3** and **x2goclient 4.1.1.1-2**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a non-backward compatible change in libssh, which broke one of the corner cases in SCP protocol (aka CVE-2019-14889). This is already [fixed](https://code.x2go.org/gitweb?p=x2goclient.git;a=commit;h=ce559d163a943737fe4160f7233925df2eee1f9a) in the x2goclient (it was already fixed for windows clients before) and now it is just matter of time to get this into your favorite distribution (preferrably through bug report in their bug tracker https://bugs.launchpad.net/):

Also you can use a nightly builds repo https://launchpad.net/~x2go/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
There is a fixed x2goclient with version 4.1.2.2-0~1884~ubuntu available and it`s working.

Comment: thank you for your feedback dear friend!

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary dirty solution for this.

This seems to be an issue with the most recent updates of `libssh` which broke `scp`. Downgrading the `libssh-4 package` to its last version and restarting the `x2goclient` fixed it to me.

This can be done with `apt`, or `synaptic`:

search for `libssh-4`, click on it, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> or package->Force version, and choose the earlier one

[image]

Keep in mind that holding old packages isn't recommended and this was a patch for some CVE, so might be all back to normal in future updates.

Comment: which version exactly have you installed, I don't see any options under ctrl-e

Comment: I edited my reply with an image showing the version I choose.

Comment: cool, unfortunately this doesn't help in my case... screenshot doesn't match description, its libssh-grypt, not libssh

Comment: my bad... edited again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-create a new user:

```
adduser myuser2
```

and try to login with the new user & pass. If that helps, then find out the reasons of your currently-trying user permissions.